# ArgumentException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arguments

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

The error itself is:

The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Going to the app.config file of that same project I can find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DocumentsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Documents.csdl|res://*/Documents.ssdl|res://*/Documents.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;D:\Programming Projects\Desktop Applications\C#\DocumentScanner\DAL\Documents.sqlite&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The connection string does exist but I'm getting this error.

I'm using SQLite and .NET Framework 3.5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this answer? Does it help?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f5904b4d-b2f8-421e-90de-339f93959533/

Quoting:

> My only guess is the app.config is not
>   in the binary directory where the exe
>   is. Please do the following:
>   1.    Visually verify that the app.config with the expected content
>   is in the directory where the exe is
>   compiled. (Existence in the project
>   root directory is not enough.)
>   2.    Use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
>   from within your app to examine the
>   content of the app.config your exe is
>   using.   I’m also looking at the
>   content of the connection string, and
>   I can say that it may not work in a
>   multi project environment (unless
>   you’ve duplicated the EDM in each
>   project). The reason for that is “.”
>   resolves to the directory where the
>   exe is loaded from. If you want to
>   reuse the same EDM, you at least have
>   to make a few steps back in the path
>   and then navigate to the project where
>   the EDM is, e.g.
>   “......\Proj1\AdventureWorksModel”.
>   Additionally you may consider using
>   the |DataDirectory| macro - when you
>   load an AppDomain you can set
>   |DataDirectory| to point to the exact
>   directory where the EDM is, and then
>   use that in the connection string,
>   e.g.
>
> “|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorksModel”.
>   If you are working on an ASP.NET
>   project, you can use “~” which refers
>   to the project root. In that latter
>   case, you can’t reference a model
>   outside your project’s hierarchy
>   though.
>
> ```
> Zlatko Michailov Program Manager,
> ```
>
> Data Programmability Runtime Microsoft
>   Corp.