# Does SQLite work well with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, orm

The reason I ask is because when trying it out, this happens:

[ArgumentException was unhandled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064814/argumentexception-was-unhandled)

Both the Data Access Library project and the actual Winforms project use .NET 3.5 and there's this bug that rendered everything to a screeching halt.

Maybe I shouldn't use an ORM with SQLite and just use plain SQL statements?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it works fine... I've used it with both EF 3.5 and 4.0, without serious issues.

I think your error is due to a configuration problem. Make sure the name of the connection string is correct in app.config

Answer (score 1):

The only time I had that error (or similar) was when the app.config wasn't in the binary folder or the sqlite binary wasn't there. Besides those obvious to solve problems I never had problems with using EF together with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I believe EF only comes out of the box with a provider for Sql server. So i assume that you've used a 3rd party provider to get it to work with sqlite?

I'd simply try using another provider until you find one that works well. If you can't find one, you could consider forking the existing one ?

Or you could use nhibernate, it's a bit more mature than EF and will work well, however the IDE support isn't as nice.